# Python Error at QGIS startup

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am unable to solve the following python error in the General tab of the Log Messages when I startup QGIS:

```
2021-03-29T09:19:03     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 121, in loadAlgorithms
    alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
    File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 66, in loadAlgorithm
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    File "", line 724, in exec_module
    File "", line 860, in get_code
    File "", line 791, in source_to_code
    File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\plugin_upload.py", line 20
    print "Connecting to: %s" % hidepassword(address)
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the processing tab of the log messages I get the following as well:

```
2021-03-29T09:19:03     CRITICAL    Could not import script algorithm 'export_to_CSV' from 'C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\export_to_CSV.py'
    module 'processing' has no attribute 'getObject'
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

You have two custom processing tools in `C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts` containing syntax errors.

You either have to fix these errors *(syntax error at line 20 in plugin_upload.py and module 'processing' has no attribute 'getObject' in export_to_CSV.py)* or remove these two tools from the folder. If you remove them, QGIS will no longer try to load them and the error will disappear.